# Change the form.text programmatically with a button of other form

Tags: c#

I can't update the first form of my application. when it opens it loads all the elements, then through a button I open a second form and from that, with a button I should reload all the controls of the first form including form1.text but this does not happen. despite the marker I saw that the text variable is updated correctly, however on a graphic level it does not change.

form1:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
       public string mail { get; private set; }
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
        }
        public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Text = "table - Last Update: " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
             ...some other code...
        }
        public void updateform()
        {
            this.Controls.Clear(); 
            InitializeComponent(); 
            Form1_Load(null, null);
            this.Refresh();
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            mail = lbl1.Text;
            Form2 form2 = new Form2(mail);
            form2.Show();
        }
}
```

form2:

```
 public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2(String stringa)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            email = stringa;

        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1 f1 = new Form1();
            f1.updateform();
            this.Close();
        }
```

Comment: From your `Form2` you need to reference you the `Form1` you initialize first. This line... `Form1 f1 = new Form1();`, creates a new form that doesn't reference the first form but is a whole new instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a reference to Form1, into Form2 using the `Show()` command.  The reference can be accessed using the `.Owner` property.

In Form1:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mail = lbl1.Text;
    Form2 form2 = new Form2(mail);
    form2.Show(this); // <-- pass reference to Form1
}
```

In Form2:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 f1 = this.Owner as Form1; // <-- attempt to convert .Owner to Form1
    if (f1 != null)
    {
        f1.updateform();
    }
    this.Close();
}
```